# What kind of bug is in this photo

Tags: species-identification

Wondering what kind of bug this is found outside [image]

Comment: I'm no expert, but it looks like a potato beetle to me: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorado_potato_beetle Might be helpful to list location and other info to help people orient to what the possibilities could be.

Comment: Yes, it is robust like a Colorado potato beetle (Chrysomelidae), but its antennae give it away as a scarab.

Answer (score 2):

That is a Ten-lined June Beetle, (*Polyphylla decemlineata*) in the family Scarabeidae. You can tell its a scarab by its lamellate antennae. The stripes indicate the species.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten-lined_June_beetle

Comment: Agreed as to genus; the species may be in error (we need a location to be sure); see [here](https://bugguide.net/node/view/8123/tree) for a list of North American possibilities.

Comment: Yes, I may have been premature.